# DMV in SQL 2008 to replace dm_os_exec_requests

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-management-views

I've been going through an old SQL 2005 performance tuning document and it talks about the dynamic management view `sys.dm_os_exec_requests`. It looks like that view is no longer available in SQL 2008.

Is there a direct replacement? Is there a standard way of selecting the same data from another DMV or group of DMVs?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a typo in this document http://www.coeo.com/presentations/Coeo_SQL_Waits_SQLBits.pdf :)

Comment: based on the PDF the answer should be sys.dm_exec_reques, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That DMV never existed, I just tried it on 2005 also

there is `sys.dm_exec_requests` and that returns the data in the slide attached as a comment

maybe it was a typo

sys.dm_os_* are the following dmvs

sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
sys.dm_os_child_instances
sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes
sys.dm_os_dispatcher_pools
sys.dm_os_hosts
sys.dm_os_latch_stats
sys.dm_os_loaded_modules
sys.dm_os_memory_brokers
sys.dm_os_memory_cache_clock_hands
sys.dm_os_memory_cache_counters
sys.dm_os_memory_cache_entries
sys.dm_os_memory_cache_hash_tables
sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
sys.dm_os_memory_nodes
sys.dm_os_memory_objects
sys.dm_os_memory_pools
sys.dm_os_nodes
sys.dm_os_performance_counters
sys.dm_os_process_memory
sys.dm_os_schedulers
sys.dm_os_stacks
sys.dm_os_sys_info
sys.dm_os_sys_memory
sys.dm_os_tasks
sys.dm_os_threads
sys.dm_os_virtual_address_dump
sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
sys.dm_os_wait_stats
sys.dm_os_workers

Comment: A quick Google search shows that Kevin Kline references it in a slide deck [here](http://kevinekline.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/POTW-5Min-Health-Check.pdf) (see Page 19), so I'm thinking it must have existed at some point. Perhaps in beta only?

Comment: I doubt it, the output from that matches what sys.dm_exec_requests returns...I will ping Kevin and see what he says

Comment: Thanks! That's one problem with my using intellisense to try to find it... as soon as I typed "dm_os" it removed the dm_exec_requests DMV as a potential for what I was trying to find.